# How to convert a 13 digit time to 10 digit time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime, time, milliseconds

The backend time that is being returned to the server is a 13 digit time, such as 1606712400000. This is the response from this rendering:

```
res.status(200).send(Date.now().toString());
```

I think it has something to do with converting it to milliseconds, utc, udf, etc.

But I would like the time to be in a different time. A time that will return 10 digits instead of 13. If i could figure this out, then the time for the chart will be correct. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `Date.now()` always produces 13 digits because it's in milliseconds.

Comment: @VLAZ—only between about 9 Sep 2001 and 16 Nov 5138 for positive values. :-)

Comment: @RobG np, I'd come back and amend my comment when it's no longer correct ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can divide given milliseconds by 1000 to turn them into seconds but be carefull when working with unix timestamps.